# Running yarn start on Windows 10 keeps failing

Tags: windows, npm, yarnpkg

I am moving a web project from my Mac to a Windows 10 PC. I used Github Desktop to download all of files and I'm using Visual Studio Code to work on my project. Everytime I run both `npm start` or `yarn start` I get this error. I have tried deleting `yarn.lock`,`package-lock.json`, `node_modules`, using other script terminals, clearing my cache, `npm install` `npm rebuild`, `yarn install`. Everything I could find didn't work and I have no clue what to do. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the error message:

```
Starting the development server...

events.js:200
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000/"' ]
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, look carefully at this:

```js
{
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/s', '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', '"http://localhost:3000/"' ]
}
```

1. `errno: 'ENOENT'` means the file or directory is not found
2. `path: 'cmd'` denotes the executable `cmd` was not found locally or globally while spawning process `cmd` via Node.js
3. Now, I don't want to go into details. Just know that your operating system needs to keep track of some variables which can be accessed globally. One of such variable is called `$PATH`. The executables inside directories mentioned in the `$PATH` can be accessed from anywhere on your system.
4. Here, `'C:\Windows\system32'` is a path where windows keeps some critical executables. `cmd.exe` is one of them. Somehow the path was deleted from the $PATH variable. In order to fix the problem, an easy solution is:

   - Go to `start-menu` -> `search` and type `environment variables` and open it
   - There will be a variable named PATH. Append `C:\Windows\system32` to it and press OK. If you're on Windows 7 or below, add a semi-colon `;` before it
   - Restart your terminal or IDE or code editor and try running the app. See if the error comes again